# Can I enter Romania after my first Schengen entry is exhausted?

Tags: schengen, romania, bulgaria

My travel plan is Istanbul-Schengen-Morocco-Romania-Bulgaria. I have a double entry visa for Schengen valid till 27th May 2018. I exhaust my first Schengen entry when i enter Schengen zone from Istanbul. With my second entry for Schengen still valid, I wanted to know if i am allowed to fly from Morocco to Romania on the 23rd May 2018 and stay there for two days and further on fly to Bulagria on the 25th May 2018 and get a week long visa (or atleast two day visa considering last date of my Schengen Visa as 29th May).